# NSFetchedResultsController and Searching - Return multiple and single sections?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchcontroller

### EDIT:

Shout out to pbasdf for helping me solve this issue.

Fixed code:

```
   lazy var fetchedResultsController = self.getFetchedResultsController()
    var sectionKeyPath: String? = #keyPath(Object.sectionKey)
    var searchPredicate: NSCompoundPredicate?
   
    // MARK: - Return FRC:
    private func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Object> { // var fetchedResultsController:
        print("Lazy: getFetchedResultsController()")
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Object> = Object.fetchRequest()
        fetchRequest.predicate = searchPredicate
        
        let sortByKey = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Object.sectionKey), ascending: true)
        let sortByName = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Object.name), ascending: true)
        
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortByKey, sortByName]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: sectionKeyPath ?? nil,
            cacheName: nil)
        
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }
    
    private func refreshFRC() {
        fetchedResultsController = getFetchedResultsController() // Reset FRC
        do {  // Load Data:
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Fetching error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

This gives you the FRC with an optional predicate and sectionNameKeyPath. Which you can then set to your needs, and then set the changes with refreshFRC().

---

I'm working on adding search to a tableview using a NSFetchedResultsController. **My goal:**

- Return multiple sections based on first letter of object
- Return all objects into a single section when searching.

I have working code. And I can make the table do both depending on my sectionKey, I just cant figure out how to do both in the same build.

Is this normal behavior and I'm trying to do something thats not possible by changing the FRC's sectionNameKeyPath and sortDescriptors? Or am I just missing something?

```
private func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Object> {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Object> = Object.fetchRequest()
        
        let sortByKey = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Object.sectionKey), ascending: true)
        let sortByName = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Object.name), ascending: true)
        
        switch sectionKeyPath {
        case nil:
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = nil
            fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        default:
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortByKey, sortByName]
            fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        }
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortByKey, sortByName]
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20
        
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: sectionKeyPath ?? nil,
            cacheName: nil)
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        return fetchedResultsController
    }
```

---

I'm also curious if it's better to use a a single FRC for the entire viewController, or if it would be a better approach to make one for the entire list of objects, and a second only for when the search is active?

---

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
    searchBar.barStyle = .default
    
    switch searchBar.text?.count {
    case nil:
        searchPredicate = nil
        sectionKeyPath = #keyPath(Object.sectionKey)
        tableView.reloadData()
    case 0:
        searchPredicate = nil
        sectionKeyPath = #keyPath(Object.sectionKey)
        tableView.reloadData()
    default:
        sectionKeyPath = nil
        guard let searchText = searchBar.text else { return }
        setSearchPredicate(search: searchText)
    }
    fetchFRC()
    tableView.reloadData()
} // End: updateSearchResults()

func fetchFRC() {
    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Fetching error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify the problem?  You seem to say that you can get it working, but then say you can’t.

Comment: Hey there. My apologies. - I'm trying to make the FRC return one section when a user is using the search bar, and multiple sections based on the first letter of the object in the same build. - I can make both happen separately, depending on if I use the sectionNameKeyPath. - I've tried hooking the sectionNameKeyPath up to a variable that changes when the search is active, but this still is returning multiple sections when searching. - The search is also fully functional. - My problem is trying to figure out how to return multiple sections when not searching and a single section when searching.

Comment: Can you show the code that swaps between "normal" (multi-section) mode and "search" mode?  Presumably you change the sectionKeyPath and then re-call the `getFetchedResultsController` code in your question?

Comment: I added the code for updating search results. Which I'm trying to use to change the `sectionNameKeyPath`.  My assumption was that sorting also had a role in the sections due to the FRC needing to sort first by `sectionNameKeyPath`. Hence the switch in `getFetchedResultsController()`, but that also didn't work.

Comment: I think you need to re-call `getFetchedResultsController` before `fetchFRC` in that `updateSearchResults` code.

Comment: Interesting. I tried that initially but took it out because the complier was saying: `Result of call to 'getFetchedResultsController()' is unused`. But it is indeed getting ran and changed before the fetching happens...  I'll play with this a bit and see what happens. It still will only return multiple or a single section depending on what the `sectionKey` was set to first.

Comment: You must have an FRC as a variable in your view controller: you need to assign the result of the `getFetchedResultsController` call to that var.

Comment: I do `lazy var fetchedResultsController = self.getFetchedResultsController()`. It works now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments:

1. You need to re-call `getFetchedResultsController` before `fetchFRC` in that `updateSearchResults` code; and
2. You need to assign the result to the `fetchedResultsController` var defined in your view controller.